# How to migrate a TFVC project from TFS to AZDO?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

How to migrate a TFVC project from TFS to AZDO ?

***Goal:***

Is to migrate host projects on (TFS 2017) using TFVC, to switch them to Azure DevOps Service (AZDO) using TFVC there too.

***My context:***

- TFS 2017 server version 2 hosting current source projects.
- AZDO 2019 service wanting to host projects targeted on TFS.

***Context wish:***

- Keep the history of source projects (TFS) on AZDO services.
- I Just want to migrated the projects (TFS) in TFVC to (AZDO) in TFVC, without doing any TFVC -> GIT conversion.
- I would like to avoid updating the TFS 2017 server for 2018 then to
  the AZDO server to switch to AZDO services afterwards.

You understand
that is a lot of step to just want to switch a project in TFVC on
TFS2017 to a TFVC on AZDO

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to migrate is to upgrade your TFS2017 server to Azure Devops Server 2019 and then using the full fidelity import feature to upload your whole database backup to Azure Devops Service.

At the moment migration tools support TFS2018u3 as well as Azure Devops Server 2019 and 2019u1 as well as 2020 can be imported into the service. We do these kinds of imports regularly and it's a very straightforward process to restore your TFS server backup to a temporary SQL server, install the correct version of TFS/Ads and have it perform the upgrade in-place during the installation. Then use the migration tools to import the collection into Azure Devops Server. Depending on the size of your collection this may take between a couple of minutes to a couple of hours. I've done the upgrade on my laptop on certain occasions as well, installing Azure Devops Server and SQL Server Developer edition directly on Windows 10. Even a trial versions will do.

For all the details on the. Import process, see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import

If you want to import your tfvc project from one TFS servers to another TFS server/Azure Devops Server, you can detach the project collection on you current TFS server and bacmup/restore the database on another server. It will automatically be upgraded
If your project collection has multiple projects, you can delete the projects you don't need after attaching and upgrading your collection.

There are a few tools to perform a history replay from one server to another, those tools can't import everything, your changes id's will change and you'll lose the exact date a commit was made (and possibly the user who made the commit if that account no longer exists). Tools like:

- https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/

Depending on how old and how big your collection is, it may take many hours to migrate the data. If data has previously been deleted/destroyed or branched across projects or edited during branch operations, then the replay may fail or may be forced to perform alternative actions, some of these operations are no longer supported. I've used opshub on a couple of projects and some it completely failed to migrate, others migrated with incomplete or incorrect data. This was 4 years ago, maybe these were bugs and they were fixed, but since the import tools have been released we've used those almost exclusively.

PS: using tfs-git to convert (part of) your TFVC repo to git would be an alternative which I'd recommend you look into further. TFVC has been declared feature complete and has received very little love in the past few years. It's not supported by the new Multi-stage YAML pipelines, the integration for VS Code has been deprecated, the cross platform commandline tool for tfvc has been deprecated and therefore support for eclipse and rider and intellij as well. Team Explorer in VS 2019 is now pushed to the background with the release of the new git features which have escaped the Team Explorer window. It's clear that TFVC is fighting for a lost cause and that Git is winning, you'll need to switch over at some point.

Comment: I would like to avoid updating the TFS 2017 server for 2018 then to the AZDO server to switch to AZDO services afterwards.
You understand that is a lot of step to just want to switch a project in TFVC on TFS2017 to a TFVC on AZDO.

Comment: I also wonder if the opshub tool will allow me to migrate the totality of my project, knowing that the free version is limited to 1000 source control changesets.

Comment: Added more of my experience. You only need to do one upgrade of TFS 2017 to either 2018u3, 2019u2 or 2020 prior to import. I've done these on my laptop or on an Azure VM in a few hours. It's not worth the hassle of using Opshub or equivalent tools if you can prevent needing them.